# Installing tensorflow but replacing pip3 with pip because pip3 not found. Mistake?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

Installed tensorflow but replacing every mention of "pip3" with "pip" because "pip3" was not found.

It seems to have worked because I can run tensorflow scripts in qtConsole now.

Have I screwed myself in the long run somehow by not following the instructions on the website (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip), or am I good to go? If good to go, am I ok to install other things the same way?

Script I run:

```
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
...

Out[1]: [0.08017649850141025, 0.9772]
```

**Additional info**

When I say pip3 not found, I mean to say

`pip3 install -U pip virtualenv`

is met with

```
ERROR: 'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Exact same code ran with "pip" rather than "pip3" works just fine.

Comment: If you only have a Python 3 installation, `pip` and `pip3` do the same thing essentially. There's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip3` installs packages to python v3.x while `pip2` installs packages for python v2.x
Which `pip` installs packages for the default python version you have installed.
that can be python v2.x or python v3.x
Tensorflow's old versions are python v2.x supported so it worked.
There is nothing to worry about.
If you are using python2 you should definitely upgrade it to `python3`